# Replace backtick with single quote using sed or awk

Tags: php, regex, bash, sed, awk

I want to replace all backticks (`´`) with single quotation marks (`'`) in specific text document using sed or awk inside of PHP shell_exec() without using hexadecimal or octal code.

At first, I tried these commands running inside of shell script:

```
sed -e 's/´/'"'"'/g' file.txt;
sed -e 's/\´/'"'"'/g' file.txt;
sed -e 's/´/'/g' file.txt;
sed -e 's/\´/'/g' file.txt;
sed -e 's/"´"/'"'"'/g' file.txt;
awk '{gsub(/\´/, "\'" ) }1' file.txt;
```

but none of these worked.

Example of input.txt file:

```
abc´def´123`foo'456;
```

Example of output.txt file:

```
abc'def'123`foo'456
```

Using sed command running from terminal this solution works:

```
echo "a´b´c;" | sed "s/´/'/g"
```

and output is:

```
a'b'c;
```

but running it from executable file test.sh:

```
#!bin/bash
sed "s/´/'/g" input.txt > output.txt
```

as shell script executed by command

```
bash test.sh
```

it doesn't work and content of output.txt file is same as content of input.txt file.

However, with forward tick it works and result of

```
#!bin/bash
sed "s/\`/'/g" input.txt > output.txt
```

is output.txt file with content

```
abc´def´123'foo'456;
```

However, when I try to replace backward ticks with single quotation marks using hex or octal representation of characters it works like a charm.

Using sed:

```
input.txt  - abc´def´123`foo'456;
command    - sed 's/\xB4/'"'"'/g' input.txt > output.txt;
output.txt - abc'def'123`foo'456
```

Using awk:

```
input.txt  - abc´def´123`foo'456;
command    - awk '{gsub(/\264/, "\047" )}1' input.txt > output.txt;
output.txt - abc'def'123`foo'456
```

Problem is, that I'm using another script applied to the document with mentioned script that replaces every hexadecimal or octal code with its literal representation. I'm able to do it another way, I'm just curious if mentioned replacement can be used without using hex or octal code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `tr` with appropriate quoting:

```
s='abc´def´123´foo'

tr '´' "'" <<< "$s"
abc'def'123'foo
```

Running `tr` on a file:

```
tr '´' "'" < file
```

Comment: Thank you, that was quick :) With tr it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about calling scripts from php but did you try just:

```
sed "s/´/'/g" file.txt
```

Look:

```
$ echo "a´b" | sed "s/´/'/g"
a'b
```

I think you're using the wrong tick since the tr solution you say works is replacing a different tick from the one you asked to replace in your question (forward tick vs backward tick). If so then you WOULD need to escape the backtick:

```
sed "s/\`/'/g" file.txt 

$ echo "a\`b" | sed "s/\`/'/g"
a'b
```

Comment: Dont you have to escape the backtick character?

Comment: No, nothing special about it.

Comment: Just saying it "doesn't work" doesn't help us help you figure out what the problem is. Update your question to tell us if you're getting a syntax error or unexpected output or a core dump or anything else that'd help us help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Well, when used inside of terminal, it works but when used from file like this "#!bin/bash  sed "s/´/'/g" input.txt > output.txt" then the output.txt file looks exactly the same as input.txt file. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Update your question with some sample input, expected output, the script you're running, and the output you get. It sounds from your comment like the issue has nothing to do with `php` so get rid of that from your question as it's just obfuscating it. To be honest, I think you're just using the wrong quote since the `tr` solution you say works is replacing a different quote from the one you asked to replace in your question (forward tick vs backward tick) - we'll know when we see your sample input.

Comment: @Ed Morton 
I have input.txt file with just simple examle of content - `a´b´c'd"e´f`. Using `sed "s/´/'/g" input.txt > output.txt` my output.txt file looks exactly the same as input.txt file (`a´b´c'd"e´f`). Using tr (`tr '´' "'" < out.xml > out.txt`) it works with both quotes (forward and backward tick) and my output.txt file looks like this `a'b'c'd"e'f` - solution that I was expecting. When I use your solution inside of terminal like this `$ echo "a´b´c'd"e´f" | sed "s/´/'/g"` I get output `a'b'c'd"e'f` but this exactly same command doesn't work when executed as shell script from file.

Comment: Don't try to do this in a comment as the formatting's a mess. For the third and final time - update your question.

Comment: Done. Is it better now?

Comment: It would have been but you already accepted an answer so I doubt if anyone's looking at the question any more. If I were you I'd start over with a new, clear, question and lose the references to PHP if they aren't actually important.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bash:

```
while read line; do
    echo ${line//\´/\'}
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/`/'\''/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sed "s/\`/'/" file.txt
```

Comment: Your solution works great with forward tick but doesn't work with backward tick and I was asking for solution with backward ticks.

Answer (score 0):

What are you calling shell functions inside `php`? `php` has `str_replace` function that can do this job for your.

```
<?php
echo str_replace("`","'","He`lo w`rld!");
?>
```

Comment: **Note:** Works for forward and backward ticks.

Comment: I know about this solution and thank you, it works. But I'm using multiline command with shell_exec() by cron job on a large xml file with several hundred thousand lines and to use str_replace() I have to save this file into variable and it's not as effective as using language designed especially for text processing.